# How do I create a relationship with Parent and Child using cypher?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have use the `LOAD` feature to get my CSV into Neo4j. However, I am unsure how to map all of the Parent categories to the Child categories.

This is the example CSV:

```
category_id,category,description,parent_id,is_adult
4,Electronics,Electronics,0,0
5,Audio Equipment,Audio Equipment,4,0
6,Home Entertainment,Home Entertainment,4,0
7,Photography,Photography,4,0
8,Portable Audio,Portable Audio,4,0
9,Televisions,Televisions,4,0
10,Amplifiers & Receivers,Amplifiers & Receivers,5,0
11,Audio Systems,Audio Systems,5,0
12,Cassette Decks,Cassette Decks,5,0
13,CD Players,CD Players,5,0
14,Radios,Radios,5,0
15,HiFi Speakers,HiFi Speakers,5,0
17,MiniDisc Separates,MiniDisc Separates,5,0
18,Tuners,Tuners,5,0
19,DJ Equipment,DJ Equipment,5,0
20,DVD Players,DVD Players,6,0
21,DVD Recorders,DVD Recorders,6,0
22,Headphones,Headphones,6,0
23,Home Cinema,Home Cinema,6,0
24,Projectors,Projectors,6,0
25,Remote Controls,Remote Controls,6,0
26,Set Top Boxes & Receivers,Set Top Boxes & Receivers,6,0
27,VCR Players,VCR Players,6,0
29,Camcorders,Camcorders,7,0
30,Accessories,Accessories,7,0
32,Cameras,Cameras,7,0
```

As you can see category_id(11) has a parent_id(5)

The LOAD CSV command I am using is:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///tmp/categories.csv" AS row 
CREATE (:Category {category_id: row.category_id, category: row.category, description: row.description, parent_id: row.parent_id, is_adult: row.is_adult});
```

I have not used the conversion for is_adult(Boolean) yet.

I'm very new to Neo4j and would welcome any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful if you provided your `load csv`

I am not sure what you provided in the way of labels on the nodes when you imported your data but this example should find children that have not already been matched to a parent category where the parent category exists in your data (i.e. greater than equal to 4). It should then match the parent based ont eh parent id on the node and create a `:CHILD_OF` relationship between the child and the parent.

```
match (child:Category)
where not (child-[:CHILD_OF]->())
and child.parent_id >= 4
with child
match (parent:Category)
where parent.category_id = child.parent_id
create child-[:CHILD_OF]->parent
```

Comment: This is the LOAD CSV I used, although I haven't used the conversion for is_adult (Boolean) yet.

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///tmp/categories.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Category {category_id: row.category_id, category: row.category, description: row.description, parent_id: row.parent_id, is_adult: row.is_adult});

Answer (score 1):

I used your CSV file and created a db in Neo4j and then used the following the create the relationships:

```
MATCH (child:Category) WHERE child.parent_id <> 0
MATCH (parent:Category {category_id: child.parent_id})
CREATE (child)-[:CHILD_OF]->(parent)
RETURN null;
```

I see you've already selected the first (and correct) answer, but this is another way to skin the cat.

Comment: @MightyQ, you're welcome.  Note, that solution assumes that a child must have a parent_id of some value OTHER than 0 and that a parent must have a category_id of some value OTHER than 0.  If either of those two assumptions are incorrect, that solution will break at some point.  For example, if you decide to have Electronics be a child of the "InStore" and InStore will have a category_id of 0, something will need to change.